# Opening an HTML file inside a div/iframe within PHP

Tags: php, javascript, iframe, onclick, quotations

i've got this piece of code i am working on:

```
                while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
                if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
                    if (strpos($entry, '.htm',1)) {
                        echo '<a href="files\\'.$entry.'">', substr($entry, 0, strrpos($entry, '.')), '</a> <br />';
                    }
                }
            }
```

This prints html that lists filenames (.html) with a link.Now,i need the .html files that are listed to be opened inside a div rather than a new page.So i found this:

```
<a href="#Password Reset"  onclick="document.getElementById('main-text').innerHTML = '<iframe  src=\'files\\IM.htm\' width=\'100%\' height=\'100%\'></iframe>'">Password Reset</a>
```

This works just fine,exactly what i need.Opens the .html file inside an iframe/div rather than a new page.The **problem** is,when i try to echo this with PHP,i get the quotations all messy,i think,and it won't stop giving me errors.This is what i have managed to do with it:

```
echo "<a href=\"#'.$entry.'\"  onclick="document.getElementById('main-text').innerHTML = '<iframe  src=\'files\\'.$entry.'\'></iframe>'">", substr($entry, 0, strrpos($entry, '.')), "</a>";
```

Is it possible to get this to work?Sorry i am not very experienced with PHP,also i have checked for similiar posts but found nothing that could help me.Please feel free to correct any part of the code including the original working PHP code.

Thanks.

Comment: Try using ajax to load those files when the user clicks the links

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
echo '<a href="#'.$entry.'" onclick="document.getElementById(\'main-text\').innerHTML = \'<iframe  src=\'files/'.$entry.'\'></iframe>\'">'. substr($entry, 0, strpos($entry, '.')) .'</a>';
```

In PHP string concatenation is done with . instead of ,

Comment: Actually, using commas with the `echo` construct is better practice than using the '.' concatenation... http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-echo-commas-vs-concatenation/

Comment: src=\'files'.$entry.'\  doesn't that need an extra  "/" or "\" to specify the folder/directory? Also,how do i mark code in these quick replies,thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your time,however i have figured this out afterall.How do i close it?

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "<a href=\"#".$entry."\"  onclick=\"document.getElementById('main-text').innerHTML = <iframe  src=files".$entry."></iframe>;\">". substr($entry, 0, strrpos($entry, '.')) . "</a>";
```

Try that.

Comment: I've tried it and although i don't get any PHP errors from the server,i get a 'Done,but with errors' from the browser,IE7,so when i click on the hyperlinks nothing happens,thanks.

Comment: Is there a JS console for IE from where you can tell what exactly is the error? or may be try with firefox, press `Control+Shift+J` for opening JS console, and tell us what is the exact error.